# angular 2 - Karma Testing - Can't resolve all parameters for Component

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

This works fine when running, but when trying to test in Karma it all goes wrong giving me the exception

> Can't resolve all parameters for CaseActions: (?)

```
@Component({
    selector: 'case-actions',
    template: '<div>Hello!</div>'
})

export class CaseActions {
    constructor(testDi: TestDi) {

    }
}

@Injectable()
export class TestDi {

}

describe("CaseActionsComponent", () => {

    let fixture: ComponentFixture<CaseActions>;
    let comp: CaseActionsComponent;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                CaseActions
            ],
            providers: [
                {provide: TestDi, useValue: new TestDi()}
            ]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CaseActions);
        comp = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance; // BannerComponent test instance

    });

    it("Name", () => {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    })
});
```

A few of us have been trying to figure this out here and not making any progress so any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Owen

Comment: It's actually in another file, I just placed them all in the same code block for visibility, but moving it into the same file and placing it above makes no difference, still works at run-time, fails when testing.

Comment: have you tried `useClass` instead of `useValue`?

Comment: yes it when I put the providers as:`providers: [{provide: TestDi, useClass: TestDi}]` it still fails

Comment: It should work. Check your imports https://plnkr.co/edit/MTKaIz0iJU4jWkIyI0pq?p=preview

Comment: Yes it does work in your plunker example when I copy and paste it in, so looks more like a configuration issue so I'm going to turn my eyes to the webpack and karma configs see if anything stands out there.

Comment: @witchdrash did you ever find a solution? Struggling with the same thing on one of my mocked classes when testing.